# Comparing one property of an instance against an array of other instances

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, comparison

I'm trying to write an instance method for a `Card` class that compares a single card against an array. The class has some properties like: `shape` and `color`. The `otherCards` array is filled with other instances of this class, that also have their `shape`s and `color`s.

Now, I want to write a method that can check all of these attributes separately. How can I pass in a particular attribute, as in: `[allAttributesIsEqual:otherCards compareWith: self.shape]`? So I can pass in `self.shape` or `self.color` when actually comparing?

```
- (BOOL)allAttributesIsEqual: (NSArray *)otherCards
{
    //self.shape is equal to othercards.shape
}
```

Comment: And you only want to compare one property of that one instance against that same property in the whole array, and you only want a single function name?  Is there anything wrong with doing something like `-(BOOL) shapeEqual:(NSArray*) otherCards`?

Comment: Yes! I want to compare one instance of Card with all the Cards in the array. But the key is that the Cards got different properties like color and shape, and I want 1 method to check them all

Comment: I thought I had it after Dan's comment, but now I'm confused again. If you have a `Card` whose shape is square and color is blue, you want to see if a whole array of other cards are also both blue _and_ square? Or you just want to check if they're all blue?

Comment: Each card has different properties?  Or do all cards have different values in each property?

Comment: Josh: I want to ask: isAttributeEqual: self.shape: otherCards and/ or isAttributeEqual: self.color: otherCards, then compare to the correct thing in the method: color or shape... Sorry for the bad explanation I am sorta confused myself...

Comment: Tom, I've edited the title to reflect what I understand you're asking. _Please_ feel free to change it or roll it back if I've got it wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just pass in `self.shape`, because that will give you the *value* of the property. Thanks to some of Cocoa/ObjC's dynamite, however, you can pass in the *name* of a property (or method) and get the results later.

The clever (dare I say, perhaps even "Pythonic") way:

```
// The name of the property we're interested in.
NSString * key = @"color";
// Get the values of that property for all the Cards in the array, then
// collapse duplicates, because they'll give the same results when comparing
// with the single card.
NSSet * vals = [NSSet setWithArray:[arrayOfCards valueForKey:key]];
// Now, if the set has only one member, and this member is the same
// as the appropriate value of the card we already have, all objects
// in the array have the same value for the property we're looking at.
BOOL colorIsEqual = ([vals count] == 1 && [vals containsObject:[myCard valueForKey:key]]);
```

Then your method can look like this:

```
- (BOOL)allOtherCards: (NSArray *)otherCards haveEqualAttribute: (NSString *)key;
```

Dan F's suggestion to implement `- (BOOL)<#property#>Equal: (NSArray *)otherCards;` for each property you're interested in is not at all a bad idea, however. Of course, each of these could call through to the base "clever" version.

Comment: Eh, I guess it's not that Pythonic. It's hard to be Pythonic without list comprehensions.

Comment: That is pretty cool! will take me some time to get used to this way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you (as the Card class) know what it means for two instances to be "equal". It sounds like in your case, two Cards are equivalent if their color and shape properties match. Start by implementing `-isEqual:` (along with `-hash`) on your custom Card class. This is the standard way of having an object expose a notion of whether it is the same as some other object. You can implement this however you need. Within this `isEqual` method, you can check all of the relevant properties:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)otherObject
{
    if (![otherObject isKindOfClass:[self class]) {
        return NO;
    }
    Card * otherCard = (Card *)otherObject;
    // now compare the attributes that contribute to "equality"
    return ([self.shape isEqual:otherCard.shape] && [self.color isEqual:otherCard.color]);
}
```

Now, once your custom object supports this -isEqual:, you can check all the cards in the array to see if any are equal to the candidate card. You could do the loop yourself and use the -isEqual:, but the nice thing about doing this in the system standard way is that you can also use system provided convenience methods to check for collection membership, like:

```
if ([myCardList containsObject:candidateCard]) {
    // one of the cards compared as "equal"
}
```

If you would prefer to do this as you request in a method on your class, you could then structure it like so:

```
- (BOOL)isRepresentedInArray:(NSArray *)arr
{
    return [arr containsObject:self];
}
```

Comment: Based on the comments and the [repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903322/objective-c-writing-a-smart-reusable-compare-function?lq=1), Tom wants to compare only a single attribute of the cards, not check for full equality.