# Objective-C: writing a smart reusable compare function

Tags: objective-c, compare

This code is within an instance of a card class. It has properties like: self.shape, self.color. The `otherCards` NSArray is filled with other instances of this class that also got the same self.shape etc...

But I want to make a compare method that works for both shape,color,number etc. SO by passing it self.shape have it compare self.shape of `otherCards`, and by passing it self.color have it
compare self.color of `otherCards`

```
[self attributesIsEqual:self.shape with attribute:otherCards] //Calling the method


- (BOOL)attributesIsEqual: (id)attribue with: (NSArray *)otherCards
{
    // Compare whatever (id) attribute to the same attribute in otherCards
}
```

Comment: Would you review your code?  It's missing a parameter name.

Comment: This looks more or less like your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903020/comparing-one-property-of-an-instance-against-an-array-of-other-instances. Perhaps it would be better to refine/clarify the original question instead of starting a new fresh thread.

Comment: Yeah, please don't repost like this, Tom. Edit your question if need be.